# Number of zeros of $\zeta$-function with bounded imaginary part

Tags: riemann-zeta, estimation

> If $\gamma$ denotes the ordinate of a zero of $\zeta$-function, why is the number of zeros ''$\ll\log(n)$'' for $n\le\gamma<n+1$ ?

Is there a connection to prime number theorem ?

Comment: I think the result dates back to Riemann's original paper, but there's a short, more or less self-contained proof in Theorem 9.2 of Titchmarsh. The idea is to show to connect the number of zeros on a disk of radius $r$ to the growth rate of $\zeta(-1 + it)$.

Comment: @anomaly Yeah found the result, but was hoping for something more elementary, Thanks though.